# Power selection with MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, pmos

I have a question about PMOS load driver. When V1 is high then Vout should be 1.5 V and it is okay. But when V2 is high, Vout should be 3 V rather than 2.4 V.

Can anyone explain me why this 2.4 V and how can I fix this?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Can anyone explain me why this 2.4 V*

It's because of the body diode inside the M2 MOSFET: -

[image]

The 3 volts is fighting to push current through the body diode and can't win.

> *Can anyone explain me.... how can I fix this?*

One option is to use back-to-back MOSFETs as per a solid state relay: -

[image]

Picture taken from [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/92725/can-you-drive-back-to-back-mosfets-aka-a-solid-state-relay-without-using-an-op). Back-to-back MOSFETs can handle bidirectional currents: -

[image]

Picture from [here](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/products/interface-connectivity/optoelectronics/operating-models-solid-state-relays-ocmos-fet). Or use a proper power path controller like this chip that also uses bidirectional MOSFETs: -

[image]

Image from [here](https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/primer-on-powerpath-controllers-ideal-diodes-prioritizers.html).

Comment: Sorry i forgot to say thank you. I understand now and decided to use solid state relay.